# react native how to load all my local images in cache ? (expo)

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a lot of image in my folder. So if anyone runs the app I want to load all images once, then whenever the person is running again the app the images shouldnt load, it should be in the cache. How I do it in expo RN? Is that possible ? So the user have to not wait all time if he sees images.